# merge background audio file

Tags: python, linux, audio, merge

I have 2 audio files for primary and background music that I want to merge (not concatenate). The final audio file should be as long as the primary file, and if the background music is shorter then it should repeat.

If there a Linux command or a Python library that can be used to do this? [Sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/Main/HomePage) supports merging, but does not appear to allow repeating the background audio.

Comment: How did you manage to merge it? I have not been able to do it. Only merge so that one file plays after the other with -m. 
"sox -M new_input.wav myrecording.wav output_test.aiff" does not seem to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a possible solution, why not detect if the length of the background file < length of the foreground file and then construct a background file which is a loop, if necessary? Then you can pass that into sox.

You should be able to get the length from [sndhdr](http://docs.python.org/library/sndhdr.html) (look at the frames count).

As far as a python way of merging the streams, [audioop.add](http://docs.python.org/library/audioop.html) may do what you need, although if you're merging two full volume sources, you might want to reduce the volume of one of them (try -12db as a start) if you're mixing music and not.

More audio libraries can be found [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio/).