# High level audio crossfading library for python

Tags: python, audio

I am looking for a high level audio library that supports crossfading for python (and that works in linux). In fact crossfading a song and saving it is about the only thing I need.

I tried pyechonest but I find it really slow. Working with multiple songs at the same time is hard on memory too (I tried to crossfade about 10 songs in one, but I got out of memory errors  and my script was using 1.4Gb of memory). So now I'm looking for something else that works with python.

I have no idea if there exists anything like that, if not, are there good command line tools for this, I could write a wrapper for the tool.

Answer (score 1):

A list of Python sound libraries.

[Play a Sound with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307305/play-a-sound-with-python)

PyGame or Snack would work, but for this, I'd use something like [audioop](http://docs.python.org/library/audioop.html).

— basic first steps here : [merge background audio file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823480/merge-background-audio-file)

Answer (score 0):

A scriptable solution using external tools [AviSynth](http://avisynth.org/) and [avs2wav or WAVI](http://www.videohelp.com/forum/archive/avs2wav-request-t372280.html):

Create an AviSynth script file:
***test.avs***

```
v=ColorBars() 
a1=WAVSource("audio1.wav").FadeOut(50) 
a2=WAVSource("audio2.wav").Reverse.FadeOut(50).Reverse
AudioDub(v,a1+a2)
```

Script fades out on audio1 stores that in a1 then fades in on audio2 and stores that in a2.

a1 & a2 are concatenated and then dubbed with a Colorbar screen pattern to make a video. 
You can't just work with audio alone - a valid video must be generated.

I kept the script as simple as possible for demonstration purposes. Google for more details on audio processing via AviSynth.

Now using avs2wav (or WAVI) you can render the audio:

```
avs2wav.exe test.avs combined.wav
```

or

```
wavi.exe test.avs combined.wav
```

Good luck!

Some references:

[How to edit with Avisynth](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/48579-How-to-edit-with-Avisynth)

[AviSynth filters reference](http://avisynth.org.ru/docs/english/corefilters.htm)

Comment: DirectShowSource requires, um, Direct Show. The OP is looking for Linux Support.

Comment: I removed the DirectShow reference. The above was simply a proof of concept and up to the OP to adapt to his purposes.
I am aware that AviSynth can be used on Linux and the link I gave to WAVI includes source code.