# How to combine two audio files with one being the background music in PHP?

Tags: php, audio

I want to get a single audio file from two user inputs - one for background music and one for audio file. Any Ideas how to do so?

**EDIT**:
Basically, I what I want is the final file be as long as the audio file and having the background music chosen by the user. I do not want to concatenate the file but something like, overlapping of audio files.

Comment: I don't understand what you're ultimately trying to do. How does a "background" music file play into the current user file?

Comment: You need to define "get", for starters. There is nowhere near enough information to answer this question.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: The same thing that we can do in audacity. Like two audio files overlap.

Comment: I would think when you "get" the audio files (*by upload I'd assume*) your best bet would be to invoke some API call to a server side application, using the files as arguments. This hypothetical application would be any audio processing program with an API (*none come to mind, then again, I'm just going off the top here*)

Comment: @Bracketworks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823480/merge-background-audio-file the same thing I want to do with PHP. Hope I am clear?

Answer (score 0):

First, read up on the byte structure of the audio format you're using (uncompressed WAV strongly recommended, and the one I used).
Next, go through all the samples and add them together, keeping track of the maximum amplitude.
Finally, normalize the result by using the max amplitude to avoid clipping, then save.

Comment: Nice but there isnt any library to achieve this?

Comment: Not that I know of. But you could see about installing Audacity. I believe you can call that program from the command line, and therefore by `shell_exec()`. Call the right arguments, and you can achieve what you're aiming for.

Comment: Audacity's command line is very basic and seems to be just limited to opneing of files.

Comment: Okay, well maybe you can create a Chain in Audacity? I don't know, the byte-manipulating code sounds easier to me :p

Comment: But I have no idea how to do that kind of stuff.

Comment: Oh. Well sorry but I can't help then.